# Fetching JSON response data from JSON array through store

Tags: sencha-touch-2

We get a response in JSON format but we're unable to fetch and print the data.

```
var dstore = Ext.getStore('DomesticStore');
dstore.sync();
dstore.load();
console.log(dstore.getData().items);
// this line prints the output but unable to fetch inside array data.
```

Comment: Can you try and see if `console.log(dstore.getData().items[0].raw);` is working ? If your array has data this will print something

Comment: Also, please post a sample of the JSON data coming back from the server, the format has to be pretty specific.

Answer (score 1):

I have an application that gets JSON data. 
When you get the store call the on method. Then access the data by using the records array.

```
var Store1 = Ext.getStore('DomesticStore').on('load', function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {   
        if(successful == false){
            console.log("Could not load store. ");
        }
        var e;

        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
             e = records[i];
             console.log(e.get('elementname'));
        }
});
```

This will get go through the JSON array and get each value of whatever the field name is.

My JSON data looks like this

```
{   
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "United States",
            "2001": 128500000,
            "2002": 141800000,
            "2003": 160637000,
            "2004": 184819000,
            "2005": 203700000,
            "2006": 229600000,
            "2007": 249300000,
            "2008": 261300000,
            "2009": 274300000,
            "2010": 278900000,
            leaf: true
        }
    ]
}
```

I use that code to get each country from the records array and then the name field of each.